# Unable to render Mp4 Video in R Shiny App

Tags: html, r, video, shiny, mp4

All I get is a solid white background where there should be a video playing. If you click the download link in the shiny app video box, you can download a video that plays as expected in Quicktime.

Link to the source video is [here](https://sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/360/big_buck_bunny_360p_1mb.mp4). I placed the video in a www folder where my app.R file lives. I'm on a Mac using Chrome and Safari.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Video Compatibility"),

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            "side bar text"
        ),

        mainPanel(
            p("Video Below"),
            tags$video(
                src = "SampleVideo_640x360_1mb.mp4",
                type = "video/mp4",
                autoplay=TRUE,
                muted=TRUE,
                playsinline=TRUE,
                loop=TRUE,
                controls=TRUE),
            p("Video above")

        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like when you use `shinyApp` it will not automatically serve files from the `www` folder. This is likely because you are passing in functions rather than a path to an application folder so it doesn't assume you want to look in your current directory for files.

Before running `shinyApp`, you could run

```
addResourcePath("vid", directoryPath = './www')
```

and update your path for the video to be

```
src = "vid/SampleVideo_640x360_1mb.mp4",
```

This will tell shiny where to look for files with a given URL path prefix.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't change anything. BTW, same thing happens when this is on shinyapps.io

Comment: It worked for me when I tested it. In order to get the `www` working without needing to add a resource path is to have an `app.R` file in a directory and use `runApp()` on that code.

Comment: Still no luck. I tried various iterations of your suggestion, but just adding your line didn't work on my end. I also tried opening the URL in Safari, to see if it was some weird cache in Chrome.